# Could Bruce Wayne use a hook & a rope to escape from the PIT?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises

In the move The Dark Knight Rises, Bruce Wayne tries many times to escape from the Pit (prison)

[image]

As can be seen from this image, the height from the first pedestal / parapet to the top of the pit is not that much. Even though it is high, couldn't Bruce Wayne, with all his wit and intelligence, try something as simple as tying a hook to a rope and throw it towards the top, from the first parapet, rather than risk his life to jump 'vizhout zhe rope'...

Answer (score 4):

Well, if he was **really** smart, he would have just climbed the safety rope that's tied to him, right?  See, in that picture, on the right side, how far up it goes?

Though it's never explained, I believe it was some type of "right of passage" to make the climb from pedestal to pedestal.  You had to **earn** your way out.  Otherwise, everyone would have just climbed up that rope.

Of course, there's [the reality of rock climbing](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2012/07/30/the_dark_knight_rises_climbing_scenes_don_t_make_any_sense_at_all.html) to think of too...

Comment: 'Earn' theory amongst convicts / thugs doesn't quite cut it, but good effort though

Comment: So **you** explain why no one simply climbed up the rope, then.

Comment: That my dear is the right question

Comment: This answer is quite interesting. :) "You had to earn your way out".